# MySQL fetch the most recent records without use auto increment field in join

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get most recent row from multiple records into table using join in MySql

I already refer some posts in stack overflow & other blogs and try to fix my case but i think there is some other issue in my case.

I have 2 table :  1st is coupon and 2nd is coupon_data

In table coupon is carry the all coupon code and the coupon_data has the details of coupon with its redeem date and other info 
In this case coupon will be scan multiple time so its has multiple scan date

Like this

coupon

```
+----------+--------------+
| coupon_id | coupon_code |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 | coupon1      |
|        2 | coupon2      |
|        3 | coupon3      |
+----------+--------------+
```

coupon_data

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | scan_date  | coupon_code |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2018-04-18 | coupon1     |
|  2 | 2018-04-20 | coupon2     |
|  3 | 2018-04-22 | coupon2     |
|  4 | 2018-04-25 | coupon1     |
|  5 | 2018-04-27 | coupon1     |
|  6 | 2018-04-28 | coupon3     |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Now i need the most recent scene coupon with its scan_date

I tried to get data with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM coupon c
left JOIN (
SELECT MAX(id) max_id, scan_date,coupon_code
FROM coupon_data
GROUP BY coupon_code
) c_max ON (c_max.coupon_code = c.coupon_code)
left JOIN coupon_data cd ON (cd.coupon_code = c_max.coupon_code)
```

But no luck.
My goal is to fetch data like this.

```
+-------------+------------+
| coupon_code | scan_date  |
+-------------+------------+
| coupon1     | 2018-04-27 |
| coupon2     | 2018-04-22 |
| coupon3     | 2018-04-28 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Any reply is appreciate.

Comment: Your group by clause must contains both column **scan_date,coupon_code**

Answer (score 0):

If you really want only this much data and your table contains the same data that you mentioned in question then you don't need the sub query and joins.

Try something like

```
   SELECT c.coupon_code, cd.dt FROM coupon c INNER JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(scan_date) AS dt , coupon_code AS cod FROM  
     coupon_data GROUP BY coupon_code 
   ) cd 
   ON cd.cod = c.coupon_code
```

This will return you the expected result.

Try this [Demo](http://rextester.com/CII89384)

Comment: you miss the join main table in the query , i need it because i also want to fetch data from the other table and that cause the my problem.

Comment: @Rohit Hi I have updated the answer could you please check now.